# How to prevent completely empty rows when using \dotfill?

Tags: spacing, line-breaking, longtable, multicol

In the code below, I'm using `multicol` with `longtable` and it works quite good.
There is one thing I don't like: when a column has minimal overfill but the overfill is not problematic like the column with number 15 in the image, the line breaks and a completely empty line is added. I tried to add `\penalty` with different values but it had no effect.
I want to tell the code: if it's less than X mm overfill then don't add a new line.

```latex
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt,twopage]{article}
\usepackage[
    left=1.5cm,
    right=1.5cm,
    top=1.5cm,
]{geometry}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{longtable}

\newsavebox\ltmcbox
\newenvironment{fakelongtable}
        {\setbox\ltmcbox\vbox\bgroup
        \csname @twocolumnfalse\endcsname
        \csname col@number\endcsname\csname @ne\endcsname}
        {\unskip\unpenalty\unpenalty\egroup\unvbox\ltmcbox}

\begin{document}

\clearpage
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{0.85}
    \begin{fakelongtable}
        \begin{longtable}{p{4.4cm}r}
            \hangindent=1em X\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em XX\dotfill & 2 \\
            \hangindent=1em XXX\dotfill & 3 \\
            \hangindent=1em XXXX\dotfill & 4 \\
            \hangindent=1em XXXXX\dotfill & 5 \\
            \hangindent=1em XXXXXX\dotfill & 6 \\
            \hangindent=1em XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\dotfill & 15 \\
            \hangindent=1em XXX XXX XX XXX XXX XX\dotfill & 16 \\
        \end{longtable}
    \end{fakelongtable}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really related to `longtable` as far as I can see, it's mostly an artifact of `\dotfill`. I'd be interested to know if you see that in any "real" documents without the filler text.

Compare these two examples with and without the `\dotfill` on line 15

[image]

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt,twopage]{article}
\usepackage[
    left=1.5cm,
    right=1.5cm,
    top=1.5cm,
]{geometry}


\usepackage{longtable}


\begin{document}


        \begin{longtable}{p{4.4cm}r}
            \hangindent=1em X\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em XX\dotfill & 2 \\
            \hangindent=1em XXX\dotfill & 3 \\
            \hangindent=1em XXXX\dotfill & 4 \\
            \hangindent=1em XXXXX\dotfill & 5 \\
            \hangindent=1em XXXXXX\dotfill & 6 \\
            \hangindent=1em XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & 15 \\
            \hangindent=1em XXX XXX XX XXX XXX XX\dotfill & 16 \\
        \end{longtable}



        \begin{longtable}{p{4.4cm}r}
            \hangindent=1em X\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em XX\dotfill & 2 \\
            \hangindent=1em XXX\dotfill & 3 \\
            \hangindent=1em XXXX\dotfill & 4 \\
            \hangindent=1em XXXXX\dotfill & 5 \\
            \hangindent=1em XXXXXX\dotfill & 6 \\
            \hangindent=1em XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\dotfill & 15 \\
            \hangindent=1em XXX XXX XX XXX XXX XX\dotfill & 16 \\
        \end{longtable}


\end{document}
```

---

As simpler example, with no tables at all:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}


\begin{document}


\parbox[t]{4.4cm}{
            \hangindent=1em XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Y}\quad
\parbox[t]{4.4cm}{
            \hangindent=1em XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\dotfill

Y}


\end{document}
```

---

You can prevent a linebreak before the trailing `\dotfill` with `\nolinebreak`:

```
            \hangindent=1em XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\nolinebreak\dotfill & 15 \\
```

produces

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! Yes, It happened in my real document; 4 out of 74 titles where touched by this. Does it mean, a workaround would require a redefinition of `\dotfill`?

Comment: @Guest as I show in the final part of my answer (which I was typing as you commented) you can use `\nolinebreak` before the `\dotfill`  to prevent a linebreak there. Presumably you mean your real document had a trailing dotfill, I was assuming this was just "lipsum filler, like the XXX

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that your code works perfect! It already automates everything. This is exactly what I wanted to achieve. I can't upvote because of reputation. After this change all 74/74 look nice!